# How can I make my content appear next to my sidebar in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

When I call my Navbar component in App.js it appears on top of everything on the main page and I don't know how to get it so that the Navbar appears to the left of the screen with the main content component right next to it
[This is what it looks like](https://res.cloudinary.com/dpokiomqq/image/upload/v1653822260/work_lqyct5.jpg)

I'll really appreciate it if anyone can help me with this

```
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard';
import Employee from './pages/Employee';
import Salary from './pages/Salary';
import Calendar from './pages/Calendar';

function App() {
  return (
   <>
    <BrowserRouter>

       <Navbar/>
     
         <Routes>
            <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} /> 
            <Route path="salary" element={<Salary />} />
            <Route path="employee" element={<Employee />} />
            <Route path="calendar" element={<Calendar />} />

          </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
   </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the Navbar component

```
import React, { useState} from 'react'
import * as FaIcons from 'react-icons/fa';
import * as AiIcons from 'react-icons/ai';
import { IconContext } from 'react-icons';
import { SidebarData } from './SidebarData';
import './Navbar.css';

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
function Navbar() {
    const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);

    const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!sidebar);
  return (

    <>
    <IconContext.Provider value={{color: '#fff'}}>
    <div className="navbar">
        <Link to="#" className="menu-bars">
            <FaIcons.FaBars onClick={showSidebar} />
        </Link>
    </div>

    <nav className={sidebar ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
        <ul className='nav-menu-items' onClick={showSidebar} >
            <li className='navbar-toogle'>
                <Link to ="#" className='menu-bars'>
                    <AiIcons.AiOutlineClose/>
                </Link>
            </li>
            {SidebarData.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                    <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
                        <Link to ={item.path}>
                            {item.icon}
                            <span>{item.title}</span>
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                )
            })}


   
        

        </ul>

       
    </nav>
    </IconContext.Provider>

    </>
    
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

The Navbar css

```
  .navbar {
    background-color: #060b26;
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start;
    align-items: center;
  } 
  
  .menu-bars {
    margin-left: 2rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    background: none;
  }
  
  .nav-menu {
    background-color: #060b26;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    transition: 850ms;
  }
  
  .nav-menu.active {
    left: 0;
    transition: 350ms;
  }
  
  .nav-text {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 8px 0px 8px 16px;
    list-style: none;
    height: 60px;
  }
  
  .nav-text a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 95%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 16px;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  
  .nav-text a:hover {
    background-color: #1a83ff;
  }
  
  .nav-menu-items {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .navbar-toggle {
    background-color: #060b26;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  span {
    margin-left: 16px;
  }
```

Comment: can you share your navBar component? it can be fixed with simple css. but for me to create the correct css and give a good explaination i need to see the navBar component first

Comment: Can you please check now

Comment: Something like this? https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-star-w9pll3?file=/src/components/NavBar/index.jsx  if yes let me know i will write it as an answer with explaination.. if not please elaborate more on the end result..

Comment: (https://startbootstrap.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/) Something like this that the main content will be able to move to the right when the sidebar is opened